# backbone.js router doesn't work on IE6

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-6, backbone.js

When I use the Router in Backbone.js, IE6 throw a Permission Denied on the following line:

```
if (this.iframe && (frag != this.getFragment(this.iframe.location.hash)))
```

the Backbone.js version is 0.5.3 , I also try some other version, but it is not work also.

Comment: have You found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backbone.js router does work in IE6, but it uses hash fragment routing (http://domain/#route) instead of HTML5 history push state routing (http://domain/route)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know backbone.js does not claim to support IE6