# Does Backbone.js work on IE6? What types of things need to be carefully handled while trying to support IE6 with Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, internet-explorer-6

I completely understand that IE6 is almost 10 years now, but my startup has to deliver a product in China that has to support all the IE6 ridden computers in corporations here. My question is, has anyone had experience with working with Backbone.js on IE6, and if so, is it realistic to use Backbone for IE6 browsers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are [not your personal research assistants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553). If you have specific programming questions, feel free to ask them. Vague questions about "what should I think about" or "what do I need to know" are inappropriate here, as they don't fit in SO's design. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) defines clearly what is (and is not) proper to ask here, and specifically mentions general discussion questions as not being acceptable. Keeping noise and discussion down helps keep SO a useful *programming* Q&A resource. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Are you still using ie6?

Comment: In fact, IE6 is *more* than 10 years old.

Comment: anyways i found it on google and it should be answerd for this purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550912/backbone-js-router-doesnt-work-on-ie6), I wouldn't hold out too much hope.

If you're writing for IE6, you need to be looking for things that have explicit support for it, because otherwise you're almost certain to have problems with pretty much any Javascript written in the last few years.